# Webform email with list of senders

Tags: webforms, emails

I am build a webform to send emails.
I have some user local accounts.
I would like to login with personal user account and send an email, choosing from a list of possible senders.
It is possible in that webform to choose from which email I want to send?

For e.g. I have 2 emails

- email for advertise
- email for internal communication

I would like to go to webform, choose from which this 2 emails I want to sent, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Webform and in **Build tab** add field of type **Select** *(Select / Entity Select)* and define all options (email addresses from which it is possible to send emails) in your field's detail form.

Then go to Webform settings and under tab **Email handlers** add **new Email**. Fill basic fields *(subject, body)* and as your **sender** *(address from which email should be send)* select name of the **Select** field you've created earlier. As receiver *(address which should receive email)* set whatever email you need.